# How to know the resource of each task assignment on RAY

Tags: ray

I newbie in Ray, I try to run some ML training task using RAY,
I'd like to know how much CPU, RAM, and GPU each task uses.

RAY supports the dashboard to view resource information, but I need to write down to log file for easy track.

How can I write the percent of CPU, RAM, and GPU each task uses to file log.

I use Python.

Comment: `I use Python.` Consider tagging [tag:python]. And [tag:resources]. Do you want measures before, during, or after running the task? What is your requirement regarding accuracy?

Comment: thanks for your reply, I want to measure during running the task. For example, the first task takes 1204MB (RAM), 60% CPU, and 5GB Memory of GPU, and writes all that information to file log. I want to monitor from beginning to end of the task. Finally thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

That's a good question--I don't think Ray supports anything like that at the moment, but I've filed an enhancement request here: https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/16711

Comment: thank you so much, hope that RAY supports API soon.